# Python projection (bindings) for winRT?

Tags: python, windows, windows-runtime, projection

I have a python program that I want to access the accelerometer on a win10 tablet.  There is an api available for this in RT.

Does anybody know of a RT projection to Python?

Or, perhaps some other way to access the api??

Comment: Hello, have you managed to do this? I need to access the sensors in Windows 10 as well. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, no. I couldn't figure it out and decided to use HTML sensor api's as a workaround.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs

Answer (score 0):

*Update*

There is now a community-maintained fork of the project. https://github.com/pywinrt.

---

*Original answer*

It looks like there is a work-in-progress Microsoft project called "xlang" that aims to do this. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang/issues/37.